# Magento 2.0 Product page form does not show up if I enable my custom catalog_product_new.xml

Tags: magento2

The product form page seems to disappear if I enable my custom catalog_product_new.xml.

See screenshot:
[image]

I checked the log files and I see a **main.CRITICAL: Block product_tabs throws exception and cannot be rendered.**
I can't seem to point out was is the culprit although I am assuming the issue is in the catalog_product_new.xml.

This is the code I have added:

**Rahaha\AdminSample\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_new.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
            <block class="Rahaha\AdminSample\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\CustomTabz" name="custom-tab" template="product/tab/customtabz.phtml">
            </block>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product-reviews</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">custom-tab</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Rahaha\AdminSample\view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\product\tab\customtabz.phtml**

```
<fieldset class="fieldset form-inline">
<legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Custom Tab') ?></span></legend>
<br>
<div id="table_cataloginventory">
<div class="field">
   <label class="label" for="custom_first">
        <span><?php  echo __('First') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" id="custom_first" name="first" value="first">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="field">
   <label class="label" for="custom_second">
        <span><?php  echo __('Second') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" id="custom_second" name="second" value="second">
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</fieldset>
```

**Rahaha\AdminSample\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\CustomTabz.php**

```
<?php
namespace Rahaha\AdminSample\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;

class CustomTabz extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget
{
    protected $_template = 'catalog/product/tab/customtabz.phtml';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok the tab finally is working now.  Changes I have made to make it work:

Update the XML config **catalog_product_new.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
            <block class="Rahaha\AdminSample\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\RahahaProductTab" name="rahaha-tab" template="Rahaha_AdminSample::catalog/product/tab/rahahaproducttab.phtml" group="basic" />
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">product_tabs.rahahaproducttab</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">rahaha-tab</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**implement TabInterface in CustomTab**

```
class RahahaProductTab extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    public function canShowTab() {
        return true;
    }

    public function getTabLabel() {
        return _("Rahaha Integration");
    }

    public function getTabTitle() {
        return $this->getTabLabel();
    }

    public function isHidden() {
        return false;
    }
```

note: i renamed the class for personal reason, not part of solution.